# How to use some function in configurable.js in custom phtml in magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, configuration, magento2.2.2

I want to use the `_getSimpleProductId` function of **configurable.js** in my custom phtml file.

What i want to achieve is get the product id according to the customer select the configurable options.

I moved the configurable.js to my custom theme too.

How to override the configurable.js or how can i reuse this method(_getSimpleProductId)

Answer (score 0):

You can add like below code in your `requirejs-config.js` file which will be located at `Vendor/Module/view/frontend` -

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            configurable: 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/configurable'
        }
    }
};
```

Then in your phtml file call like -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','configurable'],function($){
        $(document).ready( function() {
            whichever function from configurable.js..
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can you please explain me more

Comment: What kind of explanation is needed, please help so that I can tell as much as I know?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below to override `configurable.js`
create your custom module.
Inside your module `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/` create `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'configurable': {
                'VendorName_ModuleName/js/configurable': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

now create `configurable.js` file in `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js`

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
    'use strict';

    return function(customConfigurable){
        $.widget('mage.configurable', customConfigurable, {
            _getSimpleProductId: function (element) {
                //You can do your customizations here
                return this._super(element); // this will call the parent
            }
        });
        return customConfigurable;
    };

});
```